# plotzoom unbinds datahighlight in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jqplot

I have a jqplot chart that is coupled with other elements on the side by hovering over it.
Now I want to add plotzooming to it, but after you used the zoom function, the datahover doesn't work anymore. I have no idea how to fix or test this.

I have a jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DWFTb/244/
After using the zoom, there are no more logs, so the bind events don't work anymore.

I used the bar example to implement it like this:

```
function showPoint(ev, seriesI, pointI, data){
   console.log(ev);
}
function hidePoint(ev){
    console.log('hide');
}
```

I tried changing the event "bind" to the jQuery function `on`. Didn't help.
I also tried using the `$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push('jqplotDataMouseOver', function(){...});`

Comment: it does work for me even after i zoom in http://jsfiddle.net/SXD2S/1/

Comment: You're right. It still doesn't work on my site, though. Have to find the differences... :(